# Convert a list of jsons into a dataframe and then step-by-step

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a problem. I have a list that contains `2549150` elements. However, I don't want to convert the whole list into a dataframe at once, using the `pd.json_normalize` method.

I would like to convert the list into a dataframe step by step.  First I want to convert the first 100,000 elements of the list, then from the 100,000 + 1 element the next 100,000 elements and so on.
However, the problem is that my dataframe contains `2500000` elements at the end instead of `2549150` elements. I therefore have too many and wrong elements. How can I fix the error?

In summary, I would like to convert the list into a dataframe in 100,000 steps.

```py
import pandas as pd
my_Dict = {
'_key': '1',
 'group': 'test',
 'data': {},
 'type': '',
 'code': '007',
 'conType': '1',
 'flag': None,
 'createdAt': '2021',
 'currency': 'EUR',
 'detail': {
        'selector': {
            'number': '12312',
            'isTrue': True,
            'requirements': [{
                'type': 'customer',
                'requirement': '1'}]
            }
        }   
 }
a1D= [my_Dict] * 2549150
size = 25 # Didn't want to calculate this myself, but didn't know how else to solve it.
df_complete = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(0,len(a1D),len(a1D)//size):
    #print(i)
    df = pd.json_normalize(a1D[i:i+100000], sep='_')
    #print(df.shape)
    df_complete= pd.concat([df_complete, df])
df_complete.shape
>>> [OUT]
>>> (2500000, 11)
```

Comment: hey, so you want to do 100 000 lines by 100 000 until you reached the end of dictionnary ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than step up to your guess at how many elements there should be, step by the chunk size up to the length of the array instead:

```py
df_complete = pd.DataFrame()
chunk = 100000
for i in range(0, len(a1D), chunk):
    df = pd.json_normalize(a1D[i:i+chunk], sep='_')
    df_complete = pd.concat([df_complete, df])

df_complete.shape
```

Output:

```
(2549150, 11)
```